# Squish-unsquish ligatures

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

Here is a list of some common
[ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) in Unicode (the
ones I could create with my Compose key on Debian):

```
Orig  Ascii  Lig
ae    [ae]   æ
AE    [AE]   Æ
oe    [oe]   œ
OE    [OE]   Œ
ij    [ij]   ĳ
IJ    [IJ]   Ĳ
ff    [ff]   ﬀ
fi    [fi]   ﬁ
fl    [fl]   ﬂ
ffi   [ffi]  ﬃ
ffl   [ffl]  ﬄ
```

You have two options in this challenge: use the actual UTF-8 ligatures, or use
the ASCII-only variant. If you use the actual UTF-8 ligature variants, you gain
a 20% bonus. If you use the ASCII-only variant, you may assume square brackets
will never be involved except to signify a ligature.

The challenge: given a string as input, output the same string

- with all original ligatures replaced by their expanded counterparts.

  - match greedily: `affib` becomes `aﬃb` (`a[ffi]b`), not `aﬀib` (`a[ff]ib`)
    or `afﬁb` (`af[fi]b`).
- with all "expanded" letter sequences replaced by ligatures.

  - for example, `æOEfoo` (`[ae]OEfoo`) becomes `aeŒfoo` (`ae[OE]foo`).

Do this completely independently: `ﬀi` (`[ff]i`) becomes `ffi` (`ffi`), not `ﬃ`
(`[ffi]`).

Sound simple enough? There's a catch: every time two non-ligatures overlap by
*exactly one character*, **both** of the ligatures must be inserted into the
string. Here's a few test cases to demonstrate:

```
Input   Ascii-output      Output
fij     [fi][ij]          ﬁĳ
fIJ     f[IJ]             fĲ     * remember, capitalization matters!
fffi    [ff][ffi]         ﬀﬃ
fff     [ff][ff]          ﬀﬀ
ffffi   [ff][ff][ffi]     ﬀﬀﬃ
ffffij  [ff][ff][ffi][ij] ﬀﬀﬃĳ
```

Be careful: the same greedy matching applies (note especially the last few test
cases).

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: @Mego What's the big deal? If your language of choice cannot handle æ natively, just print 0xc3 0xa6, its UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: If a language can't facilitate a given task, don't use that language for that task. That shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 213 bytes - 20% bonus = 170.4

```js
s=>eval('for(p=o="";m=s.match(r="ﬄ|ﬃ|ﬂ|ﬁ|ﬀ|Ĳ|ĳ|Œ|œ|Æ|æ|ffl|ffi|fl|fi|ff|IJ|ij|OE|oe|AE|ae",x=r.split`|`);s=s.slice(i+t.length-(p=t<"z")))o+=s.slice(p,i=m.index)+x[(x.indexOf(t=m[0])+11)%22];o+s.slice(p)')
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>                           // s = input string
  eval(`                      // use eval to avoid writing {} or return
    for(                      // iterate over each ligature match
      p=                      // p = 1 if the last match was a non-unicode ligature
        o="";                 // o = output string
      m=s.match(              // find the next ligature

        // r = regex string for ligatures (unicode and non-unicode)
        r="ﬄ|ﬃ|ﬂ|ﬁ|ﬀ|Ĳ|ĳ|Œ|œ|Æ|æ|ffl|ffi|fl|fi|ff|IJ|ij|OE|oe|AE|ae",
        x=r.split\`|\`        // x = arrray of r

      );
      s=s.slice(i+t.length    // remove the part that has been added to the output
        -(p=t<"z"))           // if we matched a non-unicode ligature, keep the last
    )                         //     character so it can be part of the next match
      o+=s.slice(p,i=m.index) // add the text before the match to the output
        +x[(x.indexOf(        // add the opposite type of the matched ligature
          t=m[0]              // t = matched text
        )+11)%22];            // (index + 11) % 22 returns the opposite index
    o+s.slice(p)              // return o + any remaining characters
  `)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>eval('for(p=o="";m=s.match(r="ﬄ|ﬃ|ﬂ|ﬁ|ﬀ|Ĳ|ĳ|Œ|œ|Æ|æ|ffl|ffi|fl|fi|ff|IJ|ij|OE|oe|AE|ae",x=r.split`|`);s=s.slice(i+t.length-(p=t<"z")))o+=s.slice(p,i=m.index)+x[(x.indexOf(t=m[0])+11)%22];o+s.slice(p)')
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="ﬀiffffij" oninput="result.textContent=solution(input.value)" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Can `r="ﬄ|ﬃ|ﬂ|ﬁ|ﬀ|Ĳ|ĳ|Œ|œ|Æ|æ|ffl|ffi|fl|fi|ff|IJ|ij|OE|oe|AE|ae",x=r.split\`|\`` be rewritten as `x="ﬄ|ﬃ|ﬂ|ﬁ|ﬀ|Ĳ|ĳ|Œ|œ|Æ|æ|ffl|ffi|fl|fi|ff|IJ|ij|OE|oe|AE|ae".split\`|\`` for -4 bytes?

Comment: @Dendrobium The `match` call requires the string separated with `|` characters.

Comment: Anyone arriving from Google, you're looking for `String.normalize()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize